# Extension problem in functional analysis using Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

‎‎Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $E \subset X$ be a linear subspace and $f_0, g_0$ be functionals on $E$ such that

$$\forall e \in E : \lvert f_0(e)\rvert + \lvert g_0(e)\rvert \leqslant \lVert e\rVert.$$

Then $f_0$ and $g_0$ can be extended to linear functionals $f$ and $g$ on $X$ with $$\forall x \in X : \lvert f(x)\rvert + \lvert g(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert.$$

(Here, "extended" means that $f_0(x) = f(x)$ and $g_0(x) = g(x)$ for $x \in E$.)

I know that I must use the Hahn-Banach theorem, and $f_0 + g_0$ and $f_0 - g_0$.

Answer (score 1):

You have listed all the ingredients in the question. Setting $s_0 = f_0 + g_0$ and $d_0 = f_0 - g_0$, the inequality

$$\lvert f_0(e)\rvert + \lvert g_0(e)\rvert \leqslant \lVert e\rVert$$

for all $e\in E$ immediately yields

$$\lvert s_0(e)\rvert \leqslant \lVert e\rVert,\quad \lvert d_0(e)\rvert \leqslant \lVert e\rVert$$

for all $e\in E$. Now extend $s_0$ to $s$ and $d_0$ to $d$ per Hahn-Banach so that

$$\lvert s(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert,\quad \lvert d(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert$$

for all $x \in X$. Set $f(x) = \dfrac{s(x) + d(x)}{2}$ and $g(x) = \dfrac{s(x)-d(x)}{2}$ to obtain extensions of $f_0$ resp. $g_0$. Show that these satisfy

$$\lvert f(x)\rvert + \lvert g(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert$$

for all $x$ by a case distinction.